# Angular material 10: Making a Date range picker open-ended

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

One of the noteworthy changes in Angular 10 was the oft-requested feature of date range selection:
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-selection

It enables you to select a start date and an end date in the same picker.

I want to use this input in a form I need, in order to filter records from a database. However, per requirements, I should be able to leave either the start date or the end date unspecified. So, I should be able to cover all the following example scenarios:

1. **15 May 2020 to 30 June 2020**: Select all records with dates in the given range
2. ***Unspecified* to 30 June 2020**: Select all records with dates up to 30 June.
3. **15 May 2020 to *Unspecified***: Select all records from 15 May onwards.

Accomplishing case 1 is pretty easy. I'm not sure how to go about accomplishing case 2 and 3.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Easiest way would be to to split from/to to separat inputs.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm also looking for possibility to choose open ended dates. -Inf/+Inf

Answer (score 1):

Just conditionally set `[min]` and `[max]` on related inputs. Setting those on `input` elements will effectively limit selection options in the datepicker

Comment: I don't want to limit the user from picking any date. For case 2, I want to pretend they've already picked the start date in the distant past. For case 3, I want to give them an option not to pick the end date at all.

Comment: I guess you have to do it programmatically. For point 2 you could bind the min value to the first DB entries date. For 3. you can only set the current date of interaction if there are no future date entries or the last futures entry in in your DB.

Comment: *I don't want to limit the user from picking any date.* Yes you do, you want to have conditionally bounded range of dates - using min/max is the way to do it.

Comment: @Antoniossss They don't. Read it again.
As I understand they want an "infinity" option. So that I could select, say, that my lifetime is 1996-present.

Yours is a good answer, but to the wrong question.